# Best place to convert Euros to US dollars in San Francisco

Tags: airports, money, exchange, california, san-francisco

Is there any place (easily accessible by someone without a car) to exchange Euros to US dollars in San Francisco other than in the airport?

For example, when I was in Lugano, Switzerland, it was far better for me to exchange the money in Taleda (if I remember correctly the name) which was in the city centre, than in the airport. The gain was significant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time, you will get the best rate and convenience by using an ATM.

Is this not an option?

Comment: I was planning to bring some Euros with me, but if the best approach is the ATM, then I will bring only a small amount of Euros with me (for the taxi etc.) and do that.

Comment: For taxies in the Euro zone, sure.  US Cabbies will not accept Euros in most cases.

Comment: @gsamaras You'd be better off using a credit card for taxis if you can. Or use Uber which you can get from San Francisco airport if you don't want to use Bart.

Comment: My tip is, use the metro system (called BART) to get from the Airport. It's quick and much cheaper than Taxis, plus None of the classic US traffic jams

Comment: It's amazing how many people don't know this, especially among the crowd who's otherwise well-informed enough to know about SE.

Answer (score 6):

San Francisco is the major financial center for US-Pacific trade and the many bank branches will exchange your Euros. There's an [exchange booth](http://www.sanfranciscocurrencyexchange.com/) in one of the largest downtown shopping malls (other locations mentioned; I am not affiliated with that link). The problem is that **exchange rates are terrible everywhere in the United States.** I don't even get a good rate as a relatively high net-worth customer on wire transactions at my regular bank, much less as a tourist walking up.

Your best bet is using your own debit card in an ATM. California used to prohibit ATM fees for ex-USA credit cards. This is no longer true, but some banks will not charge you anyway. (What your home bank does is up to them.) Your second-best bet, depending on risk tolerance for pickpockets, is to get USD in your own country.

Comment: ATM it is then, since that's seems to be the voice of the people commenting/answering here, thank you Andrew!